# ¿por qué el menú de la Navbar no se despliega en Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Desde la página de `boootstrap` copie y pegue en mi aplicación de `Angular` el siguiente código para tener la `navbar`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" routerLink="/admin-principal">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/clientes">Clientes</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Ventas</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Administradores</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Sin embargo cuando pulso el `botón navbar-toogler` para desplegar las opciones del menu, no despliega nada, esta como inactivo.

Comment: Porque esa característica depende del uso de JQuery, no basta con los estilos. En todo caso, existe la versión de Bootstrap específica para Angular llamada [`ng-bootstrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) que tal vez sea más adecuada para no depender de JQuery. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap *a secas* está diseñado para usarse con sus propios ficheros JS que añaden el comportamiento que esperas. No has añadido el código Javascript, con lo que tienes la vista, pero no el comportamiento:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" routerLink="/admin-principal">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/clientes">Clientes</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Ventas</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Administradores</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Lamentablemente este código JS usa jQuery, con lo que no se lleva nada bien con Angular. Por tanto, te recomiendo no añadir estos ficheros de Javascript a tu código Angular, sino que uses [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), que te añade los componentes de Bootstrap como componentes pregenerados para Angular, que puedes configurar fácilmente: